# How to include a js file into a custom module in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, module, custom, frontend, js-css

Added `app/code/Namespace/Customtab/view/frontend/layout/customtab_index_index.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <head>

    <css src="Namespace_Customtab::css/viewer3d.css" />

</head>
</page>
```

And paste the file in Namespace/Customtab/view/frontend/web/css/viewer3d.css

Done di:compile, but the file is not in the viewsource . Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: please show your full code of xml file

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
          <css src="Namespace_customtab::css/viewer3d.css" />
    </head>
</page>

Comment: you have to typo mistake, Namespace_customtab use Namespace_Customtab in your customtab c is capital.

Comment: Changed the mistake. But still it didn't works :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer.
Changed the xml file. Pasted the code in

```
app/code/Namespace/Customtab/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml.
```

Now its working.